# Why we can deduce big-O when substitute T(1) to a recurrence algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

**QUESTION**

I'm trying to find the complexity of an algorithm. The algorithm solves problems of size **n** by recursively solving two subproblems of *size* **n-1** and then combining the solution with *constant time*.

So, I write an recurrence:

```
T(n) =   2 * T(n-1) + 1 * O(1)
     =   4 * T(n-2) + 3 * O(1)
     =   8 * T(n-3) + 7 * O(1)
     = 2^k * T(n-k) + ((2^k)-1) * O(1)
```

I stuck at this point, therefore I do some searching on Google. Most of the examples substitute **k** with **n-1** to make **T(n-k)** becomes **T(1)**.

```
T(n) = 2^(n-1) * T(1) + ((2^(n-1))-1) * O(1) // substitute k with n - 1
```

**PROBLEM**

After that, they conclude the ***big-O*** of this recurrence is `O(2^(n-1))`.

I am so confused about it. I don't know

(i) I still do know the complexity of `T(1)`, isn't it?

(ii) how `T(1)` is related to the conclusion and

(iii) how we can find ***big-O*** from this formula `T(n) = 2^(n-1) * T(1) + ((2^(n-1))-1) * O(1)`.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
T(n) = 2^(n-1) * T(1) + ((2^(n-1))-1) * O(1)
```

Here T(1) is always constant. Because `T(n`) means the time complexity with the input size `n > k` for some large value of k. Now if n is some constant for example `n = 5`, the the time complexity of the algorithm is constant. Because to execute the algorithm for `n = 5` it will take the same time.

Remember, in time complexity we measure the growth of a function. Now the growth is constant for a constant value of n. For this logic `T(1) = constant`.

This idea has been used to find median of an array. It divides the array into a chunks of 5 elements and then claim sorting of each chunk is constant. Because the size is fixed.